# Does Shopify Liquid have a pipe to get an object property?

Tags: shopify, liquid

I currently have:

```
assign productCollectionHandle = menu.links | where: 'title', 'Product List' | first
assign productCollectionHandle = productCollectionHandle.url | remove: '/collections/'
```

is there a way to fetch the property, `url`, using another pipe to make this one line? Or does this always have to use multiple `assign`?

For example, I'd like to use a parenthesis (not allowed in Liquid)

```
assign productCollectionHandle = (menu.links | where: 'title', 'Product List' | first).url | remove: '/collections/'
```

or use a pipe like (I made this pipe up)

```
assign productCollectionHandle = menu.links | where: 'title', 'Product List' | first | attribute: 'url' | remove: '/collections/'
```

Comment: If what you are doing works, why sweat it. You get the results you need. Elegance be damned!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `map` filter to extract the URL object from the link in a new array and get the first item from that array again.

```
{{ menu.links | where: 'title', 'Product List' | first | map: "url" | first | remove: '/collections/' }}
```

You can find more info about the `map` filter here: https://shopify.github.io/liquid/filters/map/

I find it a bit overkill since you are adding two additional filters and makes it hard to read but... it's a one liner like you asked.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, probably overkill, but neat solution nonetheless.